# Printing the stack trace in C++ (MSVC)?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

In my C++ application (developed with Visual Studio 2003) and [Qt4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)#Current), I'd like to print the stack trace from a specific line of code, either to the console output or into a file.

What would it take ?
Is Qt of any help to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) by Jochen Kalmbach [MVP VC++] and available on codeproject is probably the easiest way to do this. It wraps up all of the details of dealing with the underlying StackWalk64 API.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in the public Qt API, but if you look in

> $QTDIR/src/corelib/kernel/qcrashhandler.*

you can see the beginnings of a cross-platform implementation of exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

[StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650(VS.85).aspx) in the dbghelp.dll library should do what you're looking for.