# How to determine the name of the DLL (string) that loaded my DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7

I'm writing a device driver that is loaded by a 3rd-party driver.  I need a way to determine the name of the 3rd-party driver that is loading my device driver (for debug purposes).

For example, `GetModuleFileName` will provide me the name of the executable.  I'd like instead to be able to get the DLL names.

The stack trace may be one of the following:

(a)

```
app0.exe
abc.dll <- detect "abc"
common.dll
my.dll
```

(b)

```
app1.exe
xyz.dll <- detect "xyz"
common.dll
my.dll
```

(c)

```
app2.exe
common.dll
my.dll
```

p.s. - I only need a method for C++ \ Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've got a process handle, or id of the process your `my.dll` is loaded in.

See an MSDN example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(v=VS.85).aspx which will take a snapshot of a process and give all information.

The interesting method is at `BOOL ListProcessModules( DWORD dwPID )`:

`MODULEENTRY32` has a field called `szModule` which contains the name of the module. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684225(VS.85).aspx

All module entries can be retrieved from a process using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, which requires the process id (`th32ProcessID` of `PROCESSENTRY32`).

Then you'll iterate on all modules of the snapshot using `Module32First` and `Module32Next`. Also, do not forget to close the handle given by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.

(Note: these methods are available from *kernel32.dll*)

This is called Module Walking, more on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684236(v=VS.85).aspx (described what is in this answer already)

Answer (score 0):

If it's for debug purposes only, you can just do a stackwalk

See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301892/printing-the-stack-trace-in-c-msvc) answer for details